# AVPlayer / AVAudioPlayer - Play audio fileURL from iCloud Drive (work on simulator but not iPhone) + (OSStatus error -54.)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, icloud

I'm making Audio Player.
Importing file from iCloud Drive using `.fileImporter`.

I get file URL that looks like this: `file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/_Storage/Audio-books/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/Audiobook.mp3"`

Then I pass it to audio player (tried AVPlayer and AVAudioPlayer). Both **works on iOS simulator**.
On the device after import I get error: ***The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -54.)***

I know it's possible, app called [Evermusic](https://www.everappz.com/evermusic) does quite the same with on device files.

- Is there permissions I need to be granted to play audio that stored on device?
- How can I access Container for com~apple~CloudDocs?

Thank you very much for help, any suggestions greatly appreciated, I'm seriously stuck.
For future references repo of the project: https://github.com/yaosamo/AudioPlayer

Comment: Are you using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso ?

Comment: Ohh maaann @jnpdx I was%looking into it and thought it didn't do anything turned out I wasn't using it properly.

Thank you so muchhhh! 

This is what I just tried and it worked         CFURLStartAccessingSecurityScopedResource(myURL as CFURL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` in order to get read access to those files. See documentation:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543318-cfurlstartaccessingsecurityscope

Comment: https://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2018/09/09/wrapping-urls-security-scoped-resource-methods/ this helped it's a bit unclear how to use StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource, it's basically this

let StartAccess = URL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

do  {
defer {
               if StartAccess {
                 URL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
               }
             }
        } catch { // error}


also hello Portland, I'm from Hillsboro :D

Comment: At the moment it only work when I import and play it. But once I restart app player throws same error. I think I need to move accessing file to function that passes song to the player, currently it's inside the player. Will post update.

Comment: Did you read the whole documentation page on when to start/stop the calls and when you lose access?

Comment: Yeah I haven't at the time. Now finished it and it works like a charm! Will add addition as 2nd answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jnpdx answer want to add some details, and my solution example.

**Few core things**

✅ for my app if you need to access secured audio you need to use startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

❌ you can't simple store URL and use it later, in fact you don't store fileURL at all. You need to use what's called [bookmarkData()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417795-bookmarkdata) on your URL and store it. So later you can restore URL

✅ [Watch Apple pres here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/216/)

**Here's how I import file:**

```
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $presentImporter, allowedContentTypes: [.mp3]) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let url):
            // Start accessing secured url
            let StartAccess = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            defer {
                // Must stop accessing once stop using
                if StartAccess {
                    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                }
            }
            // Creating new book
            let newBook = Book(context: viewContext)
            let _ = print("---- Access Granted?", url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource())
            // Getting bookmarkData of the URL
            let bookmarkData = try? url.bookmarkData()
            newBook.name = "\(url.lastPathComponent)"
            // Save bookmarkURL into CoreData
            newBook.urldata = bookmarkData
            // Specifiying parent item in CoreData
            newBook.origin = playlist.self
            try? viewContext.save()
    
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**Player retrieving URL:**

```
func Audioplayer(bookmarkData: Data) {

// Restore security scoped bookmark
var bookmarkDataIsStale = false
let playNow = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &bookmarkDataIsStale)

do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: playNow!)
    // Delegate listen when audio is finished
    player?.delegate = del
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("ended"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
        player?.stop()
        ended = true
        let _ = print("---- Book has ended ----")
    }
} catch let error {
    print("Player Error", error.localizedDescription)
}
player?.prepareToPlay()
player?.play()
}
```

Thank you and again here's [repo on git.](https://github.com/yaosamo/AudioPlayer)